# Angular 2 Form validation work for complete form

Tags: angular

I create a form and 2 fields are required and this is my validation class

```
   .ng-invalid {
  border:1px solid #a94442;  
  background:#fafbee;
}
```

this will not working as should be.

**this is my html code**

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.Title" name="Title" #Title>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">First name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.FirstName" name="FirstName" required #FirstName>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Last name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.LastName" name="LastName" required #LastName>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Telephone</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.Telephone" name="Telephone" #Telephone>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Fax</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [ngModel]="contactObj.Fax" name="Fax" #Fax>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Mobile</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.Mobile" name="Mobile" #Mobile>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="input-group ig-btn">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.Email" name="Email" #Email>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date of birth</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.DOB" name="DOB" #DOB>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <select class="form-control">
                                    <option>12/10/1976</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 coment">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" [disabled]="ViewContactDisable" [(ngModel)]="contactObj.Comments" name="Comments" #Comments></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group gap-bottom0">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="SaveContact(contactObj,form)" [class.hidden]="ViewContactDisable"> OK</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

and output look like this
[image]

i want only that it will work on 2 specific field not with all form .
so please guide me the correct way to do that

Comment: Can you edit and add your component code?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `.ng-invalid` class which is also apply to form when form is invalid. so remove `.ng-invalid` and use new `.invalid` class name, see in my example. and use that class to your each control of form, where you want to display invalid border around that form control.

this way you can added border to individual form component.

**Template driven form way:**

```
 .invalid {
      border:1px solid #a94442;  
      background:#fafbee;
    }

<input #email="ngModel" name="email" [class.invalid]="!email.valid && email.touched" type="email" ngModel required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$">
     {{email.valid}}
```

another way, you can do like this: **this is the Dynamic / Reactive form way**.

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!complexForm.controls['firstName'].valid && complexForm.controls['firstName'].touched}">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="first Name" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['firstName']">
      </div>
```

**onSubmit** check validation

```
<h1>Employee Form</h1>
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="formSubmit(myForm)" novalidate>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="name"
                   ngControl="name"
                   required
                   minlength="2"
                   maxlength="35"
                   [(ngModel)]="person.name" />
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div style="color: red">{{validationMessage}}</div>
</form>
```

in your Component class

```
validationMessage: string;

constructor() {

    this.validationMessage = "";
}

formSubmit(myForm: ControlGroup) {
    if (myForm.valid) {
      this.validationMessage = "Form Is Valid";
    }
    else
    {
      this.validationMessage = "Form Is Not Valid";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , first one (template driven ) is giving some error like [ERROR ->]#FirstName="ngForm" ,

Comment: if you don't know how to use template driven form, look at this example here it will help you http://embed.plnkr.co/Xmgx1x/

Comment: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("stName.touched" ngControl="FirstName"  [(ngModel)]="contactObj.FirstName" name="FirstName" required [ERROR ->]#FirstName="ngForm">
                            </div>
                        </div>
"): ContactComponent@74:269 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("stName.touched" ngControl="FirstName"  [(ngModel)]="contactObj.FirstName" name="FirstName" required [ERROR ->]#FirstName="ngForm">
       </div>
                        </div>

Comment: sorry that was my mistake you can check my answer in template driven example.

Comment: i have made one plunker look validation as you required in action here https://plnkr.co/edit/hOGwzYpYKSHBkAFJOdam?p=preview

Comment: can u please do this on submit button check, and please hide html validation (with novalidate) , in plnkr i done have permission to change ..

Comment: when i am hitting the submit without touching any field validation is not working . i want some message or same validation on button click also.pls give me some idea.

Comment: plz check my answer, i have copied from one plunker

Comment: but sir all validation message are different , so can i check condition on component . i left this , currently i m working on ur template driven solution  which is working great but validation message is not work when i am direct hit submit button.

Comment: i am using this validation 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Code"  maxlength="10" >
<label *ngIf="!AMform.controls.Code.valid && AMform.controls.Code.touched && AMform.controls.Code.invalid"> Required (Must be valid card number).
                                            </label>

Comment: for the error message you can also use an Array[] and display all error at once.

Comment: but i have to chk all condition any other idea please

Comment: plz follow these two links http://stackoverflow.com/a/37440599/2036977 and http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/22/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-3/